# $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ graded ring and $0\neq f \in R_1,$ show that $R_f \cong S[X,X^{-1}]$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, localization

Suppose $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ graded ring and $0\neq f \in R_1.$ Then I want to show that $R_f \cong S[X,X^{-1}],$ where $S=(R_f)_0$ and $X$ transcendental over $S.$

I wanted to use the isomorphism $R_f\cong R[X]/(Xf-1)$ but I was not able to get the result.

Comment: Asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121378

Comment: This is explained in EGA II.2.2.1.

Comment: @Fred Rohrer What is the full form of  EGA II.2.2.1 ?

Comment: Hope [this](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=PMIHES_1961__8_) helps...

Comment: The EGA reference assumes R to be positively graded. But I didn't check if this restrictions is really needed for the isomorphism in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to note that $A:=R_f$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring with an invertible element $f\in A_1$. The $A_0$-homomorphism $A_0[X,X^{-1}]\to A$ sending $X$ to $f$ respects $\mathbb{Z}$-gradings and is an isomorphism in degree $0$. So it must be bijective because multiplication by powers of $X$ (resp. $f$) in $A_0[X,X^{-1}]$ (resp. $A$) induces isomorphisms between homogeneous pieces.